# CENTOS 5 - How do I mount a drive from one server to the other on the network?

Tags: networking, centos, mount

I have two dedicated servers both running CENTOS 5. Both can connect using a local IP to one another. I need one server to have direct file access to certain directories on the other server.

Is there a way to mount, say, the /usr/ directory of one server to the other so it can access files directly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From one system you will need to export the /usr filesystem and on the other system you will need to mount the remote /usr using NFS.

To export the filesystem you will need to make an entry in the [**/etc/exports**](http://linux.die.net/man/5/exports) file and then run the [**/usr/sbin/exportfs**](http://linux.die.net/man/8/exportfs) program to allow it to be accessed.

Once the /usr has been exported you can use [**mount**](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) to mount it into the local filesystem. If you have systema exporting it's /usr and systemb is to mount it then

/etc/exports would have an entry like this

```
/usr     systemb(rw)
```

and

```
exportfs -a
```

would make the /usr available to systemb so

```
mount systema:/usr /mnt
```

would mount /usr into the systemb filesystem at /mnt

If you want the systema:/usr filesystem to be mounted at boot then you'll need to add an entry to /etc/fstab e.g.

```
systema:/usr      /mnt        nfs        defaults    0 0
```

Comment: Great. A combination of the two worked perfectly.  Couple things I ran into along the way in-case anyone else has the same question:

Both NFS and Portmap need to be running on both servers.  

/sbin/service portmap start
/sbin/service nfs start
chkconfig portmap on
chkconfig nfs on

Then I modified the /etc/exports on the root server

/directory     systemhost/ipaddress(rw)

Then finally mounted on the secondary server

mount -t nfs host:/directory /localdirectory

Answer (score 0):

For this, you'll want to use [NFS](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/rhel5/rhel5_administration/rhel5_ch-nfs.html).  Essentially, you'll edit /etc/exports, and put in the file system you want to share to another server, along with any options.  (Read only?  Read Write?  Allow root access?)  Then run `exportfs`, and mount that directory from the other server.  You'll want to read `man exports` for the syntax and options.  `man exportfs` & `man nfs` will help too.


--Christopher Karel

Answer (score 0):

Exporting using NFS on the server side works great.
On the client side I like to enable automounting.
Make sure the file auto.master includes a line that looks like;
/net -hosts

Use 'service autofs start' to start the service.

Then on the client 'cd /net/systema/usr' takes you into the NFS exported files.

One advantage of the automounter vs editing /etc/fstab is
that you can reboot the systems in any order.